# 6x Dual Slot GPUs on SM 2028GR-TRHT

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, processor, server, pcie

I am not extremely familiar with hardware. This question might be easy to answer.

This server has been advertised to handle 6 GPUs. My question is that can it support 6 **Dual Slot**/**Double Width** GPUs (High End Quadros, GTX 1080, Titan Xs). This is a 2U Server.

If yes, does it support consumer cards such as GTX 1080 Tis or Titan Xs? How can the power cables be routed?

Model: Supermicro 2028GR-TRHT

Supermicro's Website: https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/2u/2028/sys-2028gr-trht.cfm
[This is how the server looks like (Image from Supermicro)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkkqd.jpg)

Thank you. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Great question.  Wrong forum.  You should ask this question on SuperUser.

Comment: @Jeff I disagree - HW Recommendations is the correct forum.

Comment: @Perlator  As soon as "If yes, does it support consumer cards such as GTX 1080 Tis or Titan Xs? How can the power cables be routed?" This was asked it becomes a tech support question. Also "can it support 6 Dual Slot/Double Width GPUs." is tech support.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you told us why you want the server; what your goal is. Even without this knowledge, I will be able to answer your question.

Simply, no. The card doesn't advertise room for 6 GPUs. It advertises 6 slots that COULD be used for GPUs. Not only will it not support 6 GPUs, it will not support either GeForce or Quadro GPUs. It will only support Tesla GPUs (as described by [this chart](https://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/GPU/)).

Now, I am going to assume that you are looking for this for professional use (as a server for a company, not home use for gaming or something else). If you are looking for something with 6 GPUs because you need that much power, check out the [Nvidia VCA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/visual-computing-appliance.html). It holds 8 Nvidia Quadro GPUs and features 20 physical Intel Xeon cores, and 256 GB of RAM. While it does not include internal storage beyond a 2 TB SSD, if you are dropping the money on that beast, buying a large NAS and the 10GBps network infrastructure equipment you will want to connect all these toys won't seem expensive.

Comment: I am planning to use this server's CPU and GPU power to render 3D animations, which could benefit from using CUDA. Since the performance gain with GeForce graphics cards would be significant for me, a Tesla GPU would be overkill. Therefore a GeForce card would be preferred to minimize cost. This idea came to my mind as featured in Linus' video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhZJ66l82r8&t=790s . He was able to install consumer grade graphics cards into the server, therefore, as long it fits physically into the slot, I assume it will be compatible, am I right? The VCA is out of my budget.

Comment: It might work, but I'm not sure you want to lay down that much cash (for the GPUs) before testing it with a GPU you already have or one you borrow from a friend (also know that the server you are looking at runs Linux, and I'm not sure if you need Windows if it will work or what other problems there might be

Comment: NoahL is right. You can put in either 3 dual-slot cards or 6 single-slot cards. Moreover, the airflow is designed so that you should use flow-through cards like Tesla or FirePro - not the usual commercial-grade GPUs with individual fans.